# XPath 1.0 - Information from next node

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-1.0

I've got this partial XML:

```
 <Events>
   <Properties>
     <Property Descriptor="1">VALUE1</Property>
     <Property Descriptor="2">1</Property>
     <Property Descriptor="3">start</Property>
     </Properties>
   <Properties>
     <Property Descriptor="1">VALUE2</Property>
     <Property Descriptor="2">1</Property>
     <Property Descriptor="3">end</Property>
   </Properties>
 </Events>
```

If I'm in "VALUE1" how can I query "VALUE2" [next PROPERTIES node]?

I tried `/next-sibling` but I'm not sure how to apply it here

Comment: I hope you mean in `<Property Descriptor='1'>`, not in `VALUE1`, since `VALUE1` is a text node that has no siblings.

Comment: ...by the way, see my updated answer, which (1) is revised based on @LarsH providing a clearer interpretation of the question, and (2) includes an XMLStarlet command line which can be used to run it and demonstrate correct output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want `following-sibling`.

Demonstrating from the top of your document:

```
//Property[@Descriptor="1"][1]/../following-sibling::Property[1]
```

If you're already at the property with descriptor 1:

```
./following-sibling::Property[1]
```

---

The above was based on a misreading of the question. See instead:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//Property[@Descriptor="1"][1]' \
  -v '../following-sibling::Properties[1]/Property[@Descriptor=./@Descriptor][1]' \
  -n <foo.xml
```

The first `-m` argument simply finds the first `Property`; the magic is in the `-v`, which looks for the sibling `Properties` and finds a `Property` within it with a matching `Descriptor`.

Comment: I can't use // as there's more properties with this name

Comment: This is selecting Property 2 I suppose :(

Comment: I'm only using the `//` in my example to get Property 1. Since you're already starting there, you'd leave out that part, and start at `./following-sibling::Property[1]`. I thought that was obvious.

Comment: Also, indexing in XPath is 1-indexed, not 0-indexed as in C and most other languages, so this is in fact the immediate next thing, not the one after that.

Comment: @Dalek, as I already said, you need to be starting from the Property, not from the text node. If you're starting from the text node, use a `../` instead of `./`. Anyhow, the whole reason I gave the first form is that it's something that I **actually tested**. If you're going to claim that it doesn't work, then, you'll need to provide a reproducer under which it doesn't.

Comment: This answer was accepted, so maybe it meets the OP's need, but it's not what he asked for, which was how to find the "next PROPERTIES node". I interpret that to mean `<Properties>` rather than `<Property>`, and this agrees with the OP's statement that he's looking for "VALUE2".

Comment: @LarsH, ...ahh! That makes sense. I've adjusted it appropriately; thank you for the catch.